# static image position for specific location using CSS Hover

Tags: html, css, image, position, mousehover

Super new to CSS and need some help! I want to hover over some text, and have my image show up in s specific spot on my page and not pop-up around the text. I tried changing the location of the photo, but no matter what I try, it stays in the same place, hovering around the text. Your help would be much appreciated!

```css
#image {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  right: 10%;
}

#text:hover+#image {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="hotlistContainer" class="col-md-6">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <p id="text">Some Text</p>
    <div id="image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made a [mcve] for you

Comment: where you wanna place the image , i am having a hard time understanding your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the position of the image to `absolute`.

```css
#image {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10%;
}

#text:hover + #image {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="hotlistContainer" class="col-md-6">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <p id="text">Some Text</p>
        <div id="image">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Although hungersoft answered the questions but here is css code with an extra few lines . 
This will make the image visible only when the **#text** is hover . Not the whole line .

```css
#image {
          display: none;
          position: absolute;
          right: 10%;
        }
        #text {
    width: 70px;
    }
    
    #text:hover+#image {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
<body>
<div id="hotlistContainer" class="col-md-6">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <p id="text">Some Text</p>
    <div id="image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! This was also very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Only change the position relative to absolute, and then you can move the image 
where you want, like this

```css
#image {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10%;
  top:100px;
}

#text:hover + #image {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="hotlistContainer" class="col-md-6">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <p id="text">Some Text</p>
    <div id="image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```